# Comments in Blogger displaying as 0

Tags: blogger, comments

I'm wondering why blogger displays my comments count on the main page as 0 and yet when I click through to the Post page I have 28 comments.

Can anyone help me? I'd be super grateful!

http://goingtoseed.blogspot.com.au

Screen shot of Main page view showing Thoughts From Friends (0)
[image]

But Click through to Post page and it shows I have 28 Comments...

Comment: Are they held up awaiting your approval? Comment moderation choices are in Settings > Posts and Comments > Comment Moderation.